# Text editor in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

my question on the picture.  In VSCode i have simple problem, when i write some tags in HTML file i have blur selection in string beggining. I tried to get back default settings, but it couldn't help.

```
    <div class="hh1">

    </div>

    <div class="hh2">

    </div>

    <div class="hh3">

    </div>
```

[image: This is screenshot]

Comment: It looks like the [indent-rainbow extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oderwat.indent-rainbow); do you have it installed?

Comment: Yes, i do. I've deleted and problem solved. Thank you very much amigo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment, uninstalling the indent-rainbow extension looks like it will remove this